# How to make changing number of columns fill entire width and center horizontally in WPF?

Tags: wpf, grid-layout

I have a Grid with 3 Columns in WPF. Each column is filled with a Vertical Stackpanel. The first column (and its content) is always visible. the 2. and 3. column are linked to checkboxes.

And i basically want to have the columns fill the entire horizontal space while also having their content centered (the content of each column is the same) . So for example if only the first column is used, its content should be centered over the whole grid width. If the 2. column is used aswell, The whole grid space should be equaly divided for both columns and their content should be centered inside. With also the third column used, the space would be divided by 3 of course.

My idea for now was the following but i cant get the stackpanels to be centered/fill out the horizontal space.

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCheckBox}" Content="2. Durchgang" IsChecked="{Binding RVPDGsecondround}" Margin ="0,0,0,0"/>
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCheckBox}" Content="3. Durchgang" IsChecked="{Binding RVPDGthirdround}" Margin ="0,0,0,0"/>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Durchgang 1"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignBody2TextBlock}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding RVPDGsecondround, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Durchgang 2" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignBody2TextBlock}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="{Binding RVPDGthirdround, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Durchgang 3" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignBody2TextBlock}" />
                                    </StackPanel>                                                                                                    
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UniformGrid may be better suited than a Grid:

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Column 1"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility=...>
        <TextBlock Text="Column 2"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility=...>
        <TextBlock Text="Column 3"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UniformGrid>
```